# screen save session to the non volatile memory

Tags: screen

Is it possible for "screen" program to have a sessions which are
persistant on the hard drive?

Basically as long as my pc is running I can screen -r resume session, but when I reboot the sessions are gone, is there a way to preserve them on hard drive?

Comment: Asked on [unix.se]: http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/3056/70524, and the answer, of course, is no.

Comment: Yes, it's possible: it's called **Hibernation** and not **reboot**!  **;-)**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. `screen` is a program that runs under the Linux kernel. When you reboot the kernel, all programs are killed.

Comment: Actually I work on Mac, and it is quite good with recovering other things to manageable extend, I was hoping the screen could be somehow dumped as well (with regards of how many windows are closed, what are the locations opened in those windows), obviously full recovery wouldn't be possible due to a programs being closed in its windows.

Comment: Clearly you never heard of [hibernation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hibernation_(computing))?

Comment: I stated in my question that I want to save session to be preserved through reboot. How is hibernation counting as such?

Comment: @philsf: Yes, I've heard of (and use) hibernation. Hibernation and reboot are different things. Hibernation saves the system state. Reboot doesn't.